# In AngularJS, how do I setup the states/views to show the same 'view' as the 'root' view but also as a grandchild if needed?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a 'home' view a 'messaging' view and a 'conversations' view.  I want the 'home' view to always show the 'messaging' view.  That's the easy part and I've done that in the code below.  But when the user clicks on a link in the 'messaging' view I want to:

1. Navigate to the 'conversations' view (which the sample below does).
   or
2. Show the 'conversations' view as a child of 'messaging'.

Here is a link to what I have so far.  I have spent quite a bit of time trying to get this to work and haven't been able to get it to do both '1' and '2'.  Here is my current state configuration.  You can see the full example at this link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eVhPAr4zGmsbiNUKdzz3?p=preview

```
homeApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: "homeController" },
                'messaging@home': { templateUrl: 'messaging.html', controller: "messagingController" }
            }
        })
        .state('conversations', {
            url: '/conversations',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'conversations.html', controller: "conversationsController" }
            }
        })
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem. You want to give the possibility to the user to open the conversation view in a new view or to open it under the messaging view, is that correct ?

Comment: @JeanJacques - Yes.  Basically open 'conversations' full screen or inside messaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can try to use [nested states or nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) to do it.

I'm not sure it's the way you want to do it but look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ExtrvAjPclnNipACgRTg?p=preview), it does the job using nested state like this :

```
.state('home.nestedView', {
        url: '/nestedView',
        views: {
          '': { templateUrl: 'conversations.html' }
        }
    })
```

Comment: That is close, but is relying on the "ui-sref" to load the view.  I can't do that.  I need the function in the click event to load the view instead.  I changed your sample to use '$state.go(".nestedView");' in the click event and it worked.  http://plnkr.co/edit/bkuCFvrFuRHOD15MQ0PP?p=preview.  If you can update your plunk and answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Bloodhound I updated the plunker to not use `ui-sref` and use a function called on a `ng-click`. But I think you should use `ui-sref` to achieve this, because using this it's easier to read your code, you don't need to refer to your controller to know where the link goes.

Comment: How can I use ui-sref and make that logic conditional?  Remember, that's the whole point of my question.  I want one link to either change the whole view or open the view under 'messaging'.  (I'll use some logic like evaluating screen size to determine which to do.)

Comment: Oh okay, I hadn't get this point. So yes it's probably the right way to do this by using `ng-click`.